# How to get timestamp since epoch in Windows?

Tags: windows, unix, timestamp

I want to measure the time of start for a program but for this I want to get the timestamp in Windows, but I need to get the time-stamp in mili-seconds since the Unix epoch format.  (The Unix epoch is the time `00:00:00 UTC` on `1 January 1970` (or `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` `ISO 8601`).)

How can I get timestamp in milseconds since Unix epoch through a Windows command?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454112/is-there-a-way-to-get-epoch-time-using-a-dos-command-if-not-can-the-date-time

Comment: @Richard No, but I looked now and 1) first answer is in seconds. 2) second answer is not so clear. 3) seems to be about epoch in general not Unix epoch. 4) I need something to get the time stamp without getting too much overhead and I don't know how much it takes to run cscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not like this ...

Load cygwin onto your PC  (www.cygwin.org)
create a script that executes commands
  date +%s.%N
  your_applicaiton
  date +%s.%N
Open a bash shell
Run the script

Get output like
1369457045.186880000
1369457053.766895000